# Make weird errors

Tags: android, makefile

I'm trying to build the android settings apk from source for the oneplus one (cm13 branch cm-13.0-ZNH0E) so I did all the repo syncing and stuff and when I run:

```
Make Settings -j5 -k
```

I get:

> find: `dummy': No such file or directory
>   find:`dummy': No such file or directory
>   find: `dummy': No such file or directory
>   find:`dummy': No such file or directory
>   find: `dummy': No such file or directory
>   find:`dummy': No such file or directory
>   find: `dummy': No such file or directory
>   build/core/copy_headers.mk:15: warning: overriding recipe for target '/home/noahvt/BuildServer/Settings/out/target/product/bacon/obj/include/qcom/display/copybit.h'
>   build/core/copy_headers.mk:15: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '/home/noahvt/BuildServer/Settings/out/target/product/bacon/obj/include/qcom/display/copybit.h'
>   build/core/copy_headers.mk:15: warning: overriding recipe for target '/home/noahvt/BuildServer/Settings/out/target/product/bacon/obj/include/qcom/display/copybit_priv.h'
>   build/core/copy_headers.mk:15: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '/home/noahvt/BuildServer/Settings/out/target/product/bacon/obj/include/qcom/display/copybit_priv.h'
>   No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE bacon
>   Yacc: aidl <= frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_y.y
>   prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/bison/bison -d  -o /home/noahvt/BuildServer/Settings/out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.cpp frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_y.y
>   Lex: aidl <= frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_l.l
>   build/core/binary.mk:625: recipe for target '/home/noahvt/BuildServer/Settings/out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.cpp' failed
>   make: *** [/home/noahvt/BuildServer/Settings/out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.cpp] Broken pipe
>   flex-2.5.39: fatal internal error, exec of /usr/bin/m4 failed
>   frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_l.l:55: warning, rule cannot be matched
>   build/core/binary.mk:662: recipe for target '/home/noahvt/BuildServer/Settings/out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_l.cpp' failed
>   make: *** [/home/noahvt/BuildServer/Settings/out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_l.cpp] Broken pipe
>   make: *** Deleting file '/home/noahvt/BuildServer/Settings/out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_l.cpp'
>   make: Target 'Settings' not remade because of errors.

Does anyone know what this means and how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it!

**Solution: Install bison**